# ISO standards test for vibration resistance of electrical equipment

Tags: safety, testing, vibration, certification

I would like to test some electrical contacts for oxidation wear resistance in indoor environments and in cars including off road vehicles with a lot of vibration.

Are there some ISO standard tests which involve putting various currents through a contact and tying it to a jackhammer or something to test it's performance under duress?

I would like to also test the contacts at moderate vibrations and with chlorine or moisture to simulate many years of usage and to estimate a MTBF.

Where can I find a list of that sort of test?

Comment: iso.org????????

Comment: sounds like a good tip. thanks, it's to advance a home project.

Comment: iso.org has good search features and is very accessible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pay big money for any ISO specification so my first port of call would be [MIL-STD-810F](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&ved=0ahUKEwik67bHzKfPAhWmLcAKHVYCCgQQFggzMAM&url=http%3A%2F%2Fcdn2.hubspot.net%2Fhub%2F75922%2Ffile-15770438-pdf%2Fdocs%2Fstd810f.pdf&usg=AFQjCNGaQdMiYLecUK2LdpOwiU9AR7U5pw&sig2=x8YvF-jT8h0oMDMt5qiMwQ&cad=rja) which you can download for free - at least you can use this to help develop what tests you want to perform. [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIL-STD-810) is also a wiki link to what it's about.

Here's an overview: -

[image]

I'll also add that I've seen this spec quoted for components such as crystals, mems and relays so it is relevant (and free as is the case with all MIL standards from what I can tell!)

There is also MIL-STD-202G worth reading. [This](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=9&ved=0ahUKEwiI4YLrzqfPAhXJKcAKHfCGAp8QFghcMAg&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.vishay.com%2Fdocs%2F35032%2Ftestcir.pdf&usg=AFQjCNE6uIX3UJDUrFn_IOSJu_awcBs3fA&sig2=eZTm13sM9veX9SaEJdFpRA&cad=rja) document from Vishay lists several topics contained in that standard that may be useful.

Another approach is to target a few relay suppliers and see what specs they say their components adhere to and what tests they perform.